# Can we add 'off-site resources' to the list of 'don't ask' questions?

Tags: feature-request, site-scope, close-reasons

Following on from [What exactly are "off-site resources" from the "off-topic" close reason?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/what-exactly-are-off-site-resources-from-the-off-topic-close-reason)

We have this listed in our close reason,

> Questions asking to recommend or find a Mac, book, tool, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Ask Different as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, edit this question to describe the problem and what research has been done so far to solve it.

but even someone carefully reading the help pages wouldn't specifically have been informed that asking for anything from our meta list is also off-topic.

The closest we have is

> Shopping or buying recommendations. Questions that are mainly about price/time/supply constraints are considered "shopping" questions.

which isn't quite the same thing.

I get the feeling that the close reason was updated after the help/on-topic page. They just need re-synchronising.

Case in point that prompted me to raise this - [Anyone know developer forums where one can publish project proposals and seek a team?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467178/anyone-know-developer-forums-where-one-can-publish-project-proposals-and-seek-a)

Comment: Nice spot and discussion. I’m also going to look over the tour and the close reason before I take a coffee and see about proposing an answer to this. https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour